# Using IntlProvider with react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-intl

For abstraction purpose, the app I work on has a custom provider that wraps a couple of other providers (like `IntlProvider` and `CookiesProvider`). The version of `react-intl` we use in our app is still `v2` (`react-intl@2.8.0`). A simplified version of my `App.js` is:

`App.js`

```
return (
      <Provider
        value={{
          localeData,
          env,
          data
        }}>
          <IntlProvider locale={language} key={language} messages={allMessages}>
             {props.children}
          </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>
  )
```

I have setup a custom render to test components in my app. My custom render looks exactly as it is specified in the `react-intl-docs`. I have followed the official [setup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup) guides from react-testing-library.

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "@testing-library/react";

import {MyProvider} from "MyProvider";

const MyTestProvider = ({children}) => {
  return <MyProvider>{children}</MyProvider>;
};

const myTestRender = (ui, options) => render(ui, {wrapper: MyTestProvider, ...options});

export * from "@testing-library/react";
export {myTestRender as render};
```

I then render my component under test as follows:

```
import {render as renderSC} from "test-utils";
import MyComponentUnderTest from 'MyComponentUnderTest';

test("does my component render", () => {
  const {getByText} = renderSC(<MyComponentUnderTest />);
});
```

I get an error from `react-intl` which indicates it is warning, but the component that is rendered in test is empty.

```
console.error
    Warning: IntlProvider.shouldComponentUpdate(): Returned undefined instead of a boolean value. Make sure to return true or false.
```

This is what my component renders in test:

```
    <body>
      <div />
    </body>
```

Is anyone able to advise what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your exports make this problem, try these instead:

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "@testing-library/react";

import {MyProvider} from "MyProvider";

const MyTestProvider = ({children}) => {
  return <MyProvider>{children}</MyProvider>;
};

const myTestRender = (ui, options) => render(ui, {wrapper: MyTestProvider, ...options});

export default myTestRender;
```

and then use your custom renderer this way:

```
import renderSC from "test-utils";
import MyComponentUnderTest from 'MyComponentUnderTest';

test("does my component render", () => {
  const {getByText} = renderSC(<MyComponentUnderTest />);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Taghi for suggesting an answer. I would have been very surprised if the solution you suggested was indeed the answer. As far as the export matches the way I import it should not be a problem if I make it a default export or not. Is there any specific reason you think this would work different with a default export? I did try the change you suggested to confirm and the problem is still the same.

Comment: I thought maybe this line `export * from "@testing-library/react";` is creating the problem. it's not necessary because you're getting all you need from `render` method of `myTestRender` function.

Comment: So did you add `console.error` section after I answered or before it? because I think I didn't see it.

Comment: Based on what `console.error` says the problem is from `MyProvider` Component. Could you show some code from it.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to confirm that nothing was wrong with testing-library or with react-intl. The problem was the app I work on had a module mock that mocked out the functionality of react-intl. This was done for convenience when working with unit tests with Enzyme. However this module mock was stripping out all functionality I needed for IntlProvider and that was the reason I was seeing an empty div when I render the testing-library test with a wrapper.